# ReactiveForms Angular validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have some reactive form like this:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      filter: [''],
      filterReason: [''],
      documentsRequired: [''],
      urgencyReason: [''],
      reportRequestedDate: [''],
      urgencyDate: [''],
      urgencyRemarks: ['']
    });
```

And some value like this:

```
validation = false;
```

The problem I have is that i need to toggle value of that **validation** in html, and based on that if **validation = true** i need to add validation to some field that will look like this:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      filter: [''],
      filterReason: [''],
      documentsRequired: [''],
      urgencyReason: [''],
      reportRequestedDate: ['', Validation.required],
      urgencyDate: ['', Validation.required],
      urgencyRemarks: ['', Validation.required]
    });
```

How to do that even i have init form on rendering the component?

Comment: Can you make a answer please that i can try, thanks

Comment: I have added a complete stackblitz and a detailed answer below, this answer also uses `updateValueAndValidity` to make sure the new validators are run once they are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular exposes us [setValidators](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) method on `AbstractControl` so you can change validators set based on your condition:

```
onValidationChanged(validation: boolean) {
  ['reportRequestedDate', 'urgencyDate', 'urgencyRemarks'].forEach(name => {
    this.form.get(name).setValidators(validation ? Validators.required : null);
  });
}
```

Comment: You still need to run `updateValueAndValidity` on your control when you change its validators, as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a [complete StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-dynamic-validation) with **ReactiveForms** and **dynamic validation**.

The idea is to have a setter on the `validation` property so you can toggle the validators each time the property is set using `myControl.setValidators(validate ? [Validators.required] : null)` and then updating its validity state by calling `myControl.updateValueAndValidity()`

Two methods are important on your `FormControl` here:

- **setValidators()**
- **updateValueAndValidity()**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: any;
  private _validation = true;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        filter: ['Hello'],
        filterReason: ['Test'],
        documentsRequired: ['Document'],
        urgencyReason: ['Nothing'],
        reportRequestedDate: [''],
        urgencyDate: ['Today'],
        urgencyRemarks: ['']
      });
      this.setValidators(this.validation);
  }

  set validation(validate: boolean) {
    this._validation = validate;
    this.setValidators(validate);
  }
  get validation(): boolean {
    return this._validation;
  }

  setValidators(validate: boolean): void {
    this.reportRequestedDate.setValidators(validate ? [Validators.required] : null);
    this.reportRequestedDate.updateValueAndValidity();

    this.urgencyDate.setValidators(validate ? [Validators.required] : null);
    this.reportRequestedDate.updateValueAndValidity();

    this.urgencyRemarks.setValidators(validate ? [Validators.required] : null);
    this.urgencyRemarks.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log(this.form.value);
    }
  }

  get reportRequestedDate(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('reportRequestedDate') as FormControl;
  }

  get urgencyDate(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('urgencyDate') as FormControl;
  }

  get urgencyRemarks(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('urgencyRemarks') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

in your html:

```
<button  (click)="toggleValidation();">toggle validation

</button>
```

in your ts:

```
    toggleValidation(validation : boolean)
Object.keys(this.form).forEach(key=> {
this.form.get(key).setValidators(validation && key.*your condition* ? Validators.required : null); });}
```